# In oracle SQL am trying to print dates in one column which is between two date column and grouping based on ID

Tags: oracle

Below is an example, I have a similar data and I am looking to concat dates between two date fields

Table ABC

| ID | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/03/2021 | 22/05/2021 |
| 1 | 05/06/2022 | 15/06/2022 |
| 2 | 01/01/2023 | 18/04/2023 |
| 3 | 29/03/2020 | 06/06/2020 |
| 3 | 31/05/2023 | 11/07/2023 |
| 3 | 12/12/2022 | 20/03/2023 |

Am looking to get dates between From and To column and print it in Results column with separated by grouping based on ID field ;
The output should look something similar like below.

| ID | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/03/2021; 01/04/2021; 01/05/2021; 01/06/2021 |
| 2 | 01/01/2023; 01/02/2023; 01/03/2023; 01/04/2023 |
| 3 | 01/03/2020; 01/04/2020; 01/05/2020; 01/06/2020; 01/05/2023; 01/06/2023; 01/07/2023; 01/12/2022; 01/01/2023; 01/02/2023; 01/03/2023 |

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with abc (id, date_from, date_to) as
  2    (select 1, date '2021-03-12', date '2021-05-22' from dual union all
  3     select 1, date '2022-06-05', date '2022-06-15' from dual union all
  4     select 2, date '2023-01-01', date '2023-04-18' from dual union all
  5     select 3, date '2020-03-29', date '2020-06-06' from dual union all
  6     select 3, date '2023-05-31', date '2023-07-11' from dual union all
  7     select 3, date '2022-12-12', date '2023-03-20' from dual
  8    )
```

Query: find number of months between `FROM` and `TO` dates (truncated to 1st of month), and use it in `ADD_MONTHS` function to create list of required dates:

```
  9  select id,
 10    listagg(add_months(trunc(date_from, 'mm'), column_value - 1), ', ')
 11      within group (order by add_months(trunc(date_from, 'mm'), column_value - 1)) result
 12  from abc cross join
 13  table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 14                      connect by level <= months_between(trunc(date_to, 'mm'), trunc(date_from, 'mm')) + 1
 15                     ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 16  group by id;

 ID RESULT
--- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 01/03/2021, 01/04/2021, 01/05/2021, 01/06/2022
  2 01/01/2023, 01/02/2023, 01/03/2023, 01/04/2023
  3 01/03/2020, 01/04/2020, 01/05/2020, 01/06/2020, 01/12/2022, 01/01/2023, 01/02/2023, 01/03/2023, 01/05/2023, 01/06/2023, 01/07/2023

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause to generate all the months and then aggregate:

```sql
WITH months (id, "FROM", "TO") AS (
  SELECT id, TRUNC("FROM", 'MM'), TRUNC("TO", 'MM') FROM abc
UNION ALL
  SELECT id, ADD_MONTHS("FROM", 1), "TO" FROM months WHERE "FROM" < "TO"
)
SELECT id,
       LISTAGG(DISTINCT TO_CHAR("FROM", 'DD/MM/YYYY'), '; ')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "FROM") AS result
FROM   months
GROUP BY id;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ABC (ID, "FROM", "TO") AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2021-03-12', DATE '2021-05-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-06-15', DATE '2022-06-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-04-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2020-03-29', DATE '2020-06-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2023-05-31', DATE '2023-07-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2022-12-12', DATE '2023-03-20' FROM DUAL;
```

*Note: `FROM` and `TO` are reserved words and should not be used as identifiers. If you must use them then they must be quoted everywhere they are used (and a consistent case used throughout).*

Outputs:

| ID | RESULT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/03/2021; 01/04/2021; 01/05/2021; 01/06/2022 |
| 2 | 01/01/2023; 01/02/2023; 01/03/2023; 01/04/2023 |
| 3 | 01/03/2020; 01/04/2020; 01/05/2020; 01/06/2020; 01/12/2022; 01/01/2023; 01/02/2023; 01/03/2023; 01/05/2023; 01/06/2023; 01/07/2023 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/n4INroMf)